# return date type with format in java

Tags: java, date-formatting, java.util.date

I'm trying implement get method for variable has type "Date".
But when return, I want to return it with format "yyyy/MM/dd" and MUST be Date type.

Example: original date: 2018/01/01T15:00.00.000+0000

I want return: 2018-01-01 and MUST be date, not string

Can you help me in this case ?

Comment: I think you did not quite understood the differences between the Date type and outputting a date to somewhere. So please go ahead and read the docs of the Date type and also the docs of string formatting.

Comment: @Korashen, I really need clear this case. Can you help me ? my question is possible

Comment: @ᴇʟᴇvᴀтᴇ I have updated, that month not minutes

Comment: The only time you can decide how an object will be formatted, is the moment you format it by converting it from whatever class it is, to String. That is to say, you cannot when you just return it from a method. No, what you're asking is not possible. First return your Date object, then at a later time decide how it shall be formatted by converting it to String. There is no alternative to that.

Comment: @VuVuong Please do not reply to an Answer here. Please add the comment to the corresponding answer.

Answer (score 2):

A `Date` is basically stored as a number of milliseconds since the epoch (1/1/1970). It can be formatted into a `String` in various ways (e.g. with `SimpleDateFormat`), but it is never stored as a String. So, what you're asking for is impossible and makes no sense.