# Unable to convert string to date in Spanish

Tags: android, date, kotlin, locale

I'm trying to parse a String that represents a Date `"2017-05-22"` into a `Date()` using `SimpleDateFormat()`. I also need to have the date conversion in Spanish, so I'm creating a `Locale` with the spanish configuration. The problem is that for some reason I still get the output in English. My phones Language & Input configuration by default is English, but I've tried to change it to Spanish as well. Here is the full code:

```
    val localeSpanish = Locale("es", "ES")
    val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", localeSpanish)
    val dateInSpanish = dateFormat.parse("2017-01-29")
```

And I get this in the ouput:

```
Wed Jan 11 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2017
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @mTak missed an e, let me edit.

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SimpleDateFormatter.parse giving output in different format than specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50494859/simpledateformatter-parse-giving-output-in-different-format-than-specified)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by others, when you are outputting `dateInSpanish`, you are exposing a `Date` instance, which is calling its `toString` method and its implementation constructs that string based on a static array containing the words in English

```
//From java.util.Date
private final static String wtb[] = {
    "am", "pm",
    "monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday",
    "saturday", "sunday",
    "january", "february", "march", "april", "may", "june",
    "july", "august", "september", "october", "november", "december",
    "gmt", "ut", "utc", "est", "edt", "cst", "cdt",
    "mst", "mdt", "pst", "pdt"
};
```

---

When you are declaring the dateFormatter, it is meant to convert a date/string as the following example:

```
val dateFormatter = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", localeSpanish)
println(dateFormatter.parse("2017-01-29")) // prints: Wed Jan 29 00:00:00 GMT-02:00 2017
println(dateFormatter.format(Date()) // prints: 2018-07-27 (as today :p)
```

I think you should use a different mask in order to obtain the formatted string.
But if you are forced to read the date in that format, you would have to declare two formatters:

```
val readerFormatter = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", localeSpanish)
val writerFormatter = SimpleDateFormat("d 'de' MMMM 'del' yyyy", localeSpanish)
val readDate: Date = readerFormatter.parse("2017-01-29")
val dateInSpanish: String = writerFormatter.format(readDate)
println(dateInSpanish) // prints: 29 de enero del 2017 (as today :p)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I cannot write Kotlin (yet). Can you translate form Java?

```
    Locale localeSpanish = new Locale("es", "ES");
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.LONG)
            .withLocale(localeSpanish);
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("2017-01-29");
    String formattedDate = date.format(dateFormatter);
    System.out.println("Fecha en español: " + formattedDate);
```

This prints:

> Fecha en español: 29 de enero de 2017

Messages:

- The date-time classes you were using, `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`, are long outdated and poorly designed. `SimpleDateFormat` in particular has a reputation for being troublesome. And despite the name a `Date` represents a point in time, not a date. Instead use java.time, the modern Java date and time API.
- For a date without time of day use the `LocalDate` class.
- The format you are parsing, `yyyy-MM-dd`, is ISO 8601. The modern classes parse ISO 8601 as their default, that is, without any explicit formatter.
- No matter if you use `Date` or `LocalDate`, they haven’t got neither a format nor a locale in them. They just hold the data in much the same way as an `int` holds a number without any format or locale. No matter if you have an `int`, a `Date` or a `LocalDate`, if you want a specific format, you can have that format only in a `String`.
- To format a date for an audience in a locale, use a built-in date format. `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate` gives you one, but you need to convert it to the desired locale.

### Question: Can I use java.time on Android?

Yes, `java.time` works nicely on older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least Java **6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26, I’m told) the modern API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the new classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Answer (score 0):

Simple, `SimpleDateFormat.parse` returns a `Date` object which is format agnostic. What you want to do is print the following:

```
val dateString = dateFormat.format(dateInSpanish)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this for date representation and for local spanish time use your localSpanish val

```
 Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
 SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MMM dd - HH:mm:ss",*your code here*);
 String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

The line:  
`val dateInSpanish = dateFormat.parse("2017-01-29")`  
does not format the date, it just extracts the date out of the string
 
The line:

```
val localeSpanish = Locale("es", "ES")
```

does not change your phone's configuration   
so you have a date: `dateInSpanish`
and you can format it as you like and then print it