# toString() returns unexpected things on a Date object

Tags: android, date, tostring

I recently started coding my really first Android project using Android Studio 3.1.2 and SDK 19.

One of my Objects has Date attributes. At some points I want to display the whole date time or parts of it in a TextView. So I tried it the rookie way and called toString() on my Date. 
However the displayed text contains elements I didn't define in the SingleDateFormat pattern I used to create the Date Object.

This is how I create the Date on myObject:

```
Date date1;
Date date2;

SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

try {
    date1 = format.parse(json.getString("date_1"));
    dtae2 = format.parse(json.getString("date_2"));
} catch(ParseException e) {
    //error handling stuff
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This is where I want to display the Date on a View:

```
myTextView.setText("First appearance logged at " + myObject.getDate1().toString());
```

I expected a String like `2018-08-16 12:14:42` to be displayed. Instead what I get is `Thu Aug 12:14:42 GMT +02:00 2018`. This seems to be another DateFormat and ignoring my custom pattern.

So my question is, if there's a way to manipulate the output of toString(), so the Date gets displayed in the way I defined in the pattern. Can I somehow pass the pattern to the toString() method?

**EDIT**

I changed the attributes of my Objects to String type, though it's way easier for presenting. The reason to convert them into a Date is, that I need to calculate the duration between the two guys, but that's not a problem i can't solve. Thanks to the community.

Comment: To actually answer your question, subclass SimpleDateFormat and override the toString function. I personally would not do this as there are easier approaches to what you want to achieve

Comment: @InsaneCat I am sure the asker will be able to find all the answers, including yours, without a reference from these comments. Your comment has an aggressive smell to it, and it would suit you to remove it.

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [return date type with format in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50485203/return-date-type-with-format-in-java)

Comment: Storing your date-times as strings is the wrong solution. Better to use a proper date-time type and then format it (typically using a built-in format) when you need to present it to a user, like in a `TextView`.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Much of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android in the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### According to your need, you can just use `json.getString("date_1")`.

You don't need to set extra logics. Parsing is needed when you want to convert `String` date to `Date` object for some calculation.

If you want to change format of received date then use this method.

```
changeStringDateFormat(json.getString("date_1"), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", "yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Just put this method inside your Util.

```
public String changeStringDateFormat(String date, String inputDateFormat, String outPutDateFormat) {
    Date initDate = null;
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(inputDateFormat);
        initDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    SimpleDateFormat outputFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(outPutDateFormat);
    String parsedDate = outputFormatter.format(initDate);
    return parsedDate;
}
```

See **[Java Date Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html)**, It returns string from default format.

> #### public String toString()
>
> Converts this Date object to a String of the form:
>
> dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy

Comment: i think this leads to the solution I thought of. The twist is I need them as Date objects t later calculate the difference between these two guys, before I actually just passed the string from the json.

Comment: Okay, then use `json.getString("date_1")` for showing and your parsing method is correct. Also toString() does not return in format you want. If you want get string date then you have to again parse date from date.

Comment: since i got a NullPointerException on SimpleDateFormat.format() now, i'll try your suggestion :D

Comment: With some little or bigger workarounds this works for me

Comment: I don't think you have to do some extra effort, show your code, I will update it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178130/discussion-between-procra-and-khemraj).

Answer (score 1):

Simply Write this code snippet

**JAVA FILE**

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView my_text;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        my_text = findViewById(R.id.my_text);

        String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
        String date = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + date, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        my_text.setText("Your Date is :  " + date);
    }
}
```

**XML FILE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="mydemo.com.anew.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/my_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

See output:

[image]

See Screenshot of output same like your requirement get a current date:

[image]

Refer this [Tutorial](https://www.journaldev.com/17899/java-simpledateformat-java-date-format)

Hope this may help to you

Comment: Seems my architecture is a little to strangling, but I now understand how the DateFormat.format method works so it helped me well actually

Comment: Happy to halp you :) @Procra

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

Use the modern *java.time* classes instead of the terrible legacy `Date` & `SimpleDateFormat` classes.

```
myJavaUtilDate          // Never use `java.util.Date`.
.toInstant()            // Convert from legacy class to modern replacement. Returns a `Instant` object, a moment in UTC.
.atOffset(              // Convert from the basic `Instant` class to the more flexible `OffsetDateTime` class.
    ZoneOffset.UTC      // Constant defining an offset-from-UTC of zero, UTC itself.
)                       // Returns a `OffsetDateTime` object.
.format(                // Generate a `String` with text representing the value of this `OffsetDateTime` object.
    DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME  // Pre-defined formatter stored in this constant. 
)                       // Returns a `String` object.
.replace( "T" , " " )   // Replace the standard `T` in the middle with your desired SPACE character.
```

> 2018-08-16 10:14:42

## java.time

You are using terrible old classes that were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes.

If handed a `java.util.Date` object, immediately convert to `java.time.Instant`. Both represent a moment in UTC. `Instant` has a finer resolution of nanoseconds rather than milliseconds.

To convert between the legacy and modern classes, look to new conversion methods added to the old classes.

### `Instant`

```
Instant instant = myJavaUtilDate.toInstant() ;  // New method on old class for converting to/from java.time classes.
```

#### ISO 8601

To generate a `String` with text in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format similar to your desired format, call `toString`.

```
String output = instant.toString() ;  // Generate text in standard ISO 8601 format.
```

### Elapsed time = `Duration`

By the way, to calculate elapsed time, use the `Duration` classes. Pass a pair of `Instant` objects to calculate the number of 24-hour "days", hours, minutes, and seconds elapsed.

```
Duration d = Duration.between( start , stop ) ;  // Calc elapsed time.
```

> 2018-08-16T10:14:42Z

### `OffsetDateTime`

For other formatting, convert from the basic `Instant` class to the more flexible `OffsetDateTime` class.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

> odt.toString(): 2018-08-16T10:14:42Z

### `DateTimeFormatter`

Your desired format is close to the predefined formatter [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME). Just replace the `T` in the middle with a SPACE.

```
String output = odt.format( DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME )
                   .replace( "T" , " " ) ;
```

> 2018-08-16 10:14:42

### `ZonedDateTime`

Keep in mind that we are only looking at UTC so far. For any given moment, the date and the time-of-day both vary around the globe by zone.

If you want to see that same moment through the lens of the wall-clock time used by the people of a certain region (a time zone), then apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime` object.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

> zdt.toString(): 2018-08-16T11:14:42+01:00[Africa/Tunis]

You can use the same formatter as seen above to generate a string in your desired format.

```
String output = zdt.format( f ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **SimpleDateFormat** something like this:

```
String myFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);
myTextView.setText("First appearance logged at " + sdf.format(date1));
```

Comment: this would only remove the GMT part, i also want the month to be presented as number and leave out the day of week

Answer (score 0):

In my project I've been formatting using the `format()` function, like so:

`myTextView.setText("First appearance logged at " + format.format(myObject.getData1()));`

I hope that helps.